# Why drop down list appears behind the box ? Using Simple Form + Select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, simple-form

I am trying to implement a dropdown list in a simple_form but the collection of emails appears behind the main box. See image below:

[image]

I have already tried to play with z-index but failed. I have also tried to add some javascript code according to select2 documentation regarding common problems (https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems ) and also failed.

Ruby slim code is:

```
.reveal id="doubt-material-#{material.id}" data-reveal=true
  = simple_form_for [:student, trail, component, material, material_student, doubt], html: { id: "doubt" }, remote: true do |f|
    = f.input :recipient, :collection => %w[contato@witseed.com suporte@witseed.com], label: "#{t 'students.materials.index.questions.form_send_email'}", include_blank: "#{t 'students.materials.index.questions.form_blank_line'}"

    javascript:
      $('#select2-doubt_recipient-container').select2({
         dropdownParent: $('#doubt-material-#{material.id}')
      });
```

Html is:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of whats is going on ?

Thx.

Comment: Your dropdown must not be in the body of the modal. That or it's not inside it at some level. Something tells me `span` is not a positionable element too.

Comment: did you tried "postition:absolute" in select2 span?

Comment: Thanks. But I think I did not understand you point. Where in the code I put the dropdown inside the modal ? Actually where (what) is the modal ? Besides that what do you mean by "not positionable". Sorry, I am very far from being a "pro".